# Drawing a polyline from current location to a fixed location

Tags: android, google-maps

Okay, so I am developing a google maps like application using android studio. And right now I am having difficulty in understanding it. So my problem is I cannot set a specific destination that I want to go to and then draw a polyline going to it. Can somebody please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the code that you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

```
PolygonOptions rectOptions2;
rectOptions2= new PolygonOptions();
     mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick( final LatLng latLng)
                    {
    //                    PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    //                            .add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
    //                    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
                        // Creating a marker
                        BitmapDescriptor icon = 
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map);
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        markerOptions .icon(icon);
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        try {
                            final  List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
                            if (null != listAddresses && listAddresses.size() > 0) {
                               markerOptions.title(location);
                                location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                                latitude=latLng.latitude;
                                longitude=latLng.longitude;
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    //                    mMap.clear();
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        lat=latitude;
                        lng=longitude;
                        rectOptions2.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                                            polygon= mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions2);
                        polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
                        polygon.setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
                    //add lat and lng in arraylist here
                    }
                });
```